# SQL query pulling data advice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have built a CMS and using worpress databases, wp_posts & wp_postmeta.

what i am trying to accomplish is pull the data from wp_posts which will display all posts, then with the second query i am trying to pull out the image.

on wp_posts the ID is equal to the post_id on wp_postmeta

my code is working however the image on the second query is pulling the same image for all posts, how do i go about pulling the image from $ID from the first query.

---

```html
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts  
          ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 25";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    $ID           = $row['ID'];
    $post_title   = $row['post_title'];
    $post_date    = $row['post_date'];
    $post_excerpt = $row['post_excerpt'];    
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];  

   
        
   $querystrs = "
      SELECT post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' THEN meta_value END) '_wp_attached_file'
  FROM wp_postmeta
 WHERE meta_key IN('_wp_attached_file') AND post_id = '' ";
    
           $select_postmetaimage = mysqli_query($connection, $querystrs) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_postmetaimage)) {
                    
                    
                    $image = $row['key_value'];
      
    ?>


                <!-- First Blog Post -->
            
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  

               <h3><a href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $ID; ?>"><font color="white"><?php echo $post_title; ?></font></a></h3>
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <?php  echo humanTiming( strtotime($post_date) );  ?>
                 </p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="panel-body">
               
               <img class='col-md-4' align='left' width='148' src='images/<?php echo $image; ?>' alt=''>
                <p><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
                
  </div>
  <p align="right"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $ID; ?>">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> </span></a></p>
</div>
        <?php  } } ?>
```

Comment: Use one query to retrieve all the data you need at once. You need to read an introduction to databases & querying. Here, you would use a join. Please also read & act on [mcve]. Also, you say your code is working but you say it isn't working. Please use enough words & phases to say what  you actually mean.

Comment: the query is pulling all stories from the database of wp_posts but the image on the second query only pulls 1 image the same image on all posts, i tried to use INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN and all i get is a blank page

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your post, don't put them in comments. You might want to try [wordpress.so]. But you should still give a [mcve]. That's a clear description of what you want, desired output and executable input & minimal code. But you have not edited your question. Don't compress what you are trying to say into a single everyday word, we would only know what you meant by it if we already knew what you meant by it. Cut out code until it works then add enough to exhibit your error. Echo strings before you execute them & results after. *Read the definitions of inner & outer join.*

Comment: already tried inner and outer joins will not work, all i need is to join wp_posts and wp_postmeta together and pull data out of them using the post ID i was using a custom post type which had images held within the meta_value, and the meta_key is wp_attached_file which is the image.

Comment: Act on my comments.

Comment: I have been clear with my question, i have been clear with the poblem, and i have been clear with providing code that requires attention, if it was not that clear one person would not have already tried to help me, but when i post a question regarding mysql i get nothing but people telling me to go away and learn, i am just asking for a little help.

Comment: If you would like some feedback on how you are asking or could ask your question & on others' & my comments about that then you could post a question at [meta] as documented at [whats-meta] and the top bar info icon links there.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Changed image location.

I don't think the second while loop is necessary. If you add the part to fetch the image in the first query you only need to run through it once. Please try (I don't have data to confirm 100%), but it should be on the right track:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT 
        wp_posts.*, 
        (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ORDER BY meta_id DESC LIMIT 1) as image 
    FROM wp_posts 
    ORDER BY post_date DESC 
    LIMIT 0, 25";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $ID           = $row['ID'];
    $post_title   = $row['post_title'];
    $post_date    = $row['post_date'];
    $post_excerpt = $row['post_excerpt'];    
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];  
    $image        = $row['image'];
?>
    <!-- First Blog Post -->

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3><a href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $ID; ?>"><font color="white"><?php echo $post_title; ?></font></a></h3>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <?php echo humanTiming(strtotime($post_date));  ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <img class='col-md-4' align='left' width='148' src='/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>' alt=''>
            <p><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
        </div>
        <p align="right"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $ID; ?>">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> </span></a></p>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for kindly helping me the images still wont display the posys display but no image

Comment: Most defiantly on the right track I shall try and get it going thanks

Comment: Anyone see why the image may not be pulling as well

Comment: What is the result of $image, can you do a var_dump / echo and let us know?

Comment: Sorry for late reply the Result is Blank

Comment: I would need to see a dump of your wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables to try close this of.

Comment: This is a View of wp_postmeta `-- Table structure for table `wp_postmeta`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_postmeta`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
COMMIT;`